# $|G: G_s(C)| = |C|$, where $G_s(C)$ is the stablizer.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> $|G: G_s(C)| = |C|$, where $G_s(C)$ is the stablizer.

Could some one point out for me that how to see this?

Comment: This is just the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Just so this problem is answered, I'll answer this, instead of having you just google the relevant theorem.

Let $X$ be a set, and let $G$ act on $X$. For every $x\in X$, let $\text{stab}(x)$ denote the stabilizer subgroup, and $Gx$ the orbit. Define a map $G/\text{stab}(x)\to Gx$ by $(g+\text{stab}(x))\mapsto gx$. Note that since elements of $\text{stab}(x)$ fix $x$, this is actually well-defined. Conversely, define $Gx\to G/\text{stab}(x)$ by $gx\mapsto g+\text{stab}(x)$. Once again, this is well-defined since if $gx=hx$ then $gh^{-1}\in\text{stab}(x)$.

Thus, the above shows that $\#(G/\text{stab}(x))=\#(Gx)$ which is what you wanted.